# Replacement for ChannelEvent and CustomEvent in Netty 4

Tags: netty, netty4

I am working on upgrading an Netty3 application to Netty4. The application currently uses custom events by extending the `ChannelEvent` class and I am not sure how to translates this to Netty 4 because `ChannelEvent` seem to have been gone in Netty4, and unlike in Netty3, in Netty 4, there is no handler method that receives a channel event.

The current code in Netty 3 looks like this:

A custom event is defined:

```
public class CustomEvent implements ChannelEvent {}
```

and in some handler down the line, there is some code that uses the event. For example:

```
public class AppHandler extends SimpleChannelDownstreamHandler {

@Override
public void handleDownstream(ChannelHandlerContext context, ChannelEvent event) {
  event.getChannel().write(new CustomEvent(...))
  context.sendDownstream(event)

}

}
```

How can this be translated to Netty 4? Not just the custom event part but also the `context.sendDownstream(event)` method call as this is no longer in Netty 4 also.

Answer (score 0):

so either you could use the `write` method and just write it there and then in your `ChannelOutboundHandler` you can check for it or maybe you can also use `fireUserEvent`. Not sure what is a better fit for your use case.

Comment: sorry, not sure I follow. "so either you could use the write method and just write it there" ... by "write it there" what do you mean? "you can check for it " also by "check for it" how do you mean? where to check? Sorry if I am asking to much maybe some code snippet to go along with your answer will help. Thanks :)

Comment: Basically each "event" now has its own explicit method that you can call and all that you can override in the handler. You may want to read https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html